# $(a+b)^n < 2^n(a^n + b^n)$ when $ a,b>0$ will it be possible for n

Tags: induction

$(a+b)^n < 2^n(a^n + b^n)$ when $ a,b>0$ will it be possible for all natural number .

How to proceed with it by Mathematical Induction? can anyone help me?

Comment: $(a+b)^{n+1} = (a+b)^n(a+b) < 2^n(a^n + b^n)(a+b) = 2^n(a^{n+1} + ab^n + ba^n + b^{n+1}) = 2^n(a^{n+1} + b^{n+1) + 2^n(ab^n + ba^n)$.  Can you proof that $ab^n + ba^n < a^{n+1} + b^{n+1}$?  Maybe be AM-GM?

Comment: Actually, the stronger
$\,(a+b)^n \le 2^{n\color{red}{-1}}(a^n + b^n) \iff \displaystyle \frac{a+b}{2} \le \sqrt[n]{\frac{a^n + b^n}{2}}\,$ holds true by the [generalized means inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true for $n=1$:
$$(a+b)<2(a+b)$$
Assuming it is true for $n=k$, we'll show it's true for $n=k+1$:
$$(a+b)^{k+1}=(a+b)^k(a+b)<2^k(a^k+b^k)(a+b)=2^k(a^{k+1}+b^{k+1})+2^k(a^kb+ab^k)<2^{k+1}(a^{k+1}+b^{k+1}),$$
because due to rearrangement:
$$a^kb+ab^k<a^{k+1}+b^{k+1}.$$

Comment: I can not understand the last line..Can u please elaborate?

Comment: it is the rearrangement inequality. you can check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality

Comment: I  got it.....................

Answer (score 3):

Without loss of generality, suppose $a \geq b$.

Then, noting that $a, b > 0$, we have the following for $n > 0$:

$$(a+b)^n \leq (a+a)^n = (2a)^n = 2^n \cdot a^n < 2^n \cdot a^n + 2^n \cdot b^n = 2^n (a^n + b^n)$$

as desired.

Comment: Actually your proof is valid also for $n  = 0$.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco True! Okay, rather than edit, here is a full proof for the $n=0$ case: $1 < 2$. **Q.E.D.** $$ $$ (But actually: Thanks!)

Comment: Benjamin. Very nice!

Comment: @PeterSzilas I assume you refer to the $n=0$ proof in the comments: Thank you.

Comment: Benjamin. Very nice,  for n>0.:)))

Comment: This is obvious... I want an induction proof

Comment: @cmi You decided one month later to un-accept this as the answer, down-vote, and call it "obvious"?